Need help of Aave Liquidation Error Code 42 in Flash Loan Contract
I'm trying to implement a flash loan liquidation contract using Aave protocol but running into an error. My contract attempts to:

Take a flash loan from Uniswap V2 WETH/USDT pair
Use the borrowed USDT to liquidate an underwater position on Aave
Convert the received collateral back to USDT
Repay the flash loan

Here's what I'm seeing in the test output:
Account Status:

Collateral (ETH): 0
Debt (ETH): 0
Health Factor: 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935
WETH Reserve: 36309556407122758304221
USDT Reserve: 73490117144682

Flash Loan Details:

Borrowed Amount: 50000000000 USDT
Fee: 150451355 USDT
Required Repayment: 50150451355 USDT

The transaction reverts with error code 42. According to Aave's documentation, this corresponds to 'HEALTH_FACTOR_NOT_BELOW_THRESHOLD', but I'm confused because:

Why is the health factor so high (basically uint256 max)?
Why are the collateral and debt both showing as 0?

Has anyone encountered this error before? Could this be related to:

Wrong account data fetching?
Incorrect health factor calculation?
Or perhaps I'm trying to liquidate a healthy position?

Any insights would be greatly appreciated. Happy to share more code if needed.
Environment:

Local Hardhat network (forked mainnet)
Solidity 0.8.7
Testing against Aave V2 protocol

Here's the relevant code that's failing. I've simplified it to show the core logic:
'''
// Key parts of LiquidationOperator.sol
contract LiquidationOperator is IUniswapV2Callee {
// Constants
address constant WETH = 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2;
address constant USDT = 0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7;
address constant WBTC = 0x2260FAC5E5542a773Aa44fBCfeDf7C193bc2C599;
address constant WETH_USDT_PAIR = 0x0d4a11d5EEaaC28EC3F61d100daF4d40471f1852;
address constant AAVE_LENDING_POOL = 0x7d2768dE32b0b80b7a3454c06BdAc94A69DDc7A9;
address constant TEST_ACCOUNT = 0x63f6037d3e9d51ad865056bf7792029803b6eefd;

function operate() external {
    // Get account data
    (
        uint256 totalCollateralETH,
        uint256 totalDebtETH,
        ,,,
        uint256 healthFactor
    ) = ILendingPool(AAVE_LENDING_POOL).getUserAccountData(TEST_ACCOUNT);

    // Flash loan amount
    uint256 flashLoanAmount = 50000000000; // 50,000 USDT

    // Execute flash swap
    bytes memory data = abi.encode(TEST_ACCOUNT, flashLoanAmount);
    IUniswapV2Pair(WETH_USDT_PAIR).swap(0, flashLoanAmount, address(this), data);
}

function uniswapV2Call(
    address sender,
    uint256,
    uint256 amount1,
    bytes calldata data
) external override {
    require(msg.sender == WETH_USDT_PAIR, "Not authorized");
    require(sender == address(this), "Not authorized");

    (address targetAccount, uint256 flashLoanAmount) = abi.decode(data, (address, uint256));
    
    // Calculate repayment
    uint256 fee = (flashLoanAmount * 3) / 997 + 1;
    uint256 repayAmount = flashLoanAmount + fee;

    // Approve AAVE to spend USDT
    _safeApprove(USDT, AAVE_LENDING_POOL, flashLoanAmount);

    // Execute liquidation
    ILendingPool(AAVE_LENDING_POOL).liquidationCall(
        WBTC,    // collateral
        USDT,    // debt
        targetAccount,
        flashLoanAmount,
        false    // don't receive aToken
    );
    
    // Repay flash loan
    _safeApprove(USDT, WETH_USDT_PAIR, repayAmount);
    _safeTransfer(USDT, WETH_USDT_PAIR, repayAmount);
}

}
'''
The full contract includes additional interfaces and helper functions for ERC20 operations, but this is where the error occurs. Specifically, the liquidation call fails with error code 42 (HEALTH_FACTOR_NOT_BELOW_THRESHOLD).
Key questions:

Is the TEST_ACCOUNT address correct for liquidation?
Should I be checking the health factor before attempting liquidation?
Am I missing any prerequisites for the liquidation call?

Full code available if needed.
